# Does Google penalize you for using an outdated version of Wordpress?

Tags: seo, wordpress

If you are using an outdated version of Wordpress , do you get penalized for this ?
In other words, does it matter for seo ?

I know that from a security point of view it is always recommend to keep wordpress updated but on a specific site some of the custom plugins i use are not compatible with newer versions and it would break my site.

Comment: This would have nothing to do with WordPress, more with the search engine. This question may need to be moved to the WordPress site.

Comment: You really should update your custom plugins to be compatible with latest Wordpress, otherwise you might find your website distributing malware one day.

Comment: I downvoted this question just because it is way too silly. The world does not revolve around SEO. Everything does not affect SEO.

Comment: I agree with @JohnConde. There is far too much SEO related doody on the Internet most of which was never relevant. People over-think this stuff big time. I did decide to answer the question anyway JIC there is value somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

No. Google, Bing, and other search engines do not go around testing CMS and other software versions.

However, if you are using an older version of software including operating system (OS), web server, DNS, FTP, and so on, that does become compromised, you will be quickly de-listed by Google as a dangerous site. Your site will not likely drop from the index, but will likely will drop from the SERPs and being marked as dangerous.

It is the website owners responsibility to run a safe site. This includes ensuring that the software they run is not vulnerable. You do not have to run the latest greatest version, but a safe one. You should be able to check for known vulnerabilities here: http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/search?execution=e2s1 I also advise using best practices regarding security for your site.